# ArcGIS Editor for OSM, 10.8.x Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, openstreetmap, error-000816

Ran install successfully and created the OSM Toolbox but when download data give me error invalid. I am using  ArcMap 10.8.2 with Background Processing

[image]

Comment: error says target empty - would expect it to go to a geodatabase.

Comment: Please always provide errors as formatted text and not just as pictures.

Comment: Where did you download the OSM Editor from?